# Container padding EdgeInsets.fromLTRB changes background color

Tags: flutter, padding, flutter-container

I want to align a text inside a container. I used the padding class for the container which contains the text. The padding works, but it seems EdgeInsets.fromLTRB offsets the text and the background color of the container all together. Why does it happen? I can use mainAxisAlignment, but I wanted to understand why the padding class shifts the background color. Thanks.

```dart
new Container(
  width: 311,
  height: 48,
  //padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(127.5, 0, 0, 0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(0xfffb2cfef),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
  child: Row(
    //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      new Text(
        "Create account",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You use color in your decoration

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xfffb2cfef),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
```

Try removing it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I had the "Debug Paint" enabled in the Widget Inspector. Turned it off, everything is fine :)